# Constraint widget by other widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a widget like this:

[image]

But the problem I've faced with is that if title is too long it pushes the icon (triangle) out of the bounds of card.

[image]

What I want to have is the icon should always be at top right corner of the card and title to take all the available space between image and triangle, but not more. If title is too long it should just take new line.

But it should be like this:

[image]

```dart
Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
      child: Container(
        height: 130,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(product.primaryImage.url),
              height: 130,
              width: 60,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      product.name,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 8),
                    IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      iconSize: 24,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
                      onPressed: () => onRemove(product),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text("$quantityInCart x \$$price"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Wrapping title in `Expanded` doesn't work because parent `Row` gives it infinite width constraint.

Comment: Use expanded as parent for your row widget.

Comment: @OMiShah that didn't help, but wrapping `Column` in `Expanded` did it.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the column. I thought the text widget is directly under the row not under the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two Expanded like this:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text('This is quite a loooooo ooooooooo ooooooo ooooong title',
                  softWrap: true,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.add_alert)
            ],
          ),
          Text('This is a normal description')
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```